# How to run Android Simulator on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

I get the following message.

When I try to run android hello word app.

This is my setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I get the following message Waiting for device to come online.

I have being trying to emulate this for a couple hours now. I just don't understand how can something that looks so simple its giving me so much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've removed the `data.img` disk image files in the AVD folder. (an AVD is an emulator instance, just like a VM)

Please show the logcat, it will likely contain repeated error messages.
If they appear for several minutes, they are likely the cause.
[image: Android Studio Logcat button]

Answer (score -1):

I think you meat Android emulator not simulator(iOS)
Or
I may not turn on a android emulator ,if you run on device 
You turn on usb debuging (https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm) -> Connect the cable connected to the device -> click run -> select device -> OK

Comment: I'm trying to emulate the android on my computer since I don't have an android.

Comment: you can use Android emulator in android studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#runningemulator)
you search "To start the emulator:" at that